# Stop Sensors from other plugins from executing when analyzing project with sonar-runner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have created a language plugin for Sonar that scans all project files for custom violations. The problem is that when I analyze a project with sonar-runner, sensors from other language plugins are executing as well causing undesired side-effects. How would I prevent Sensors from other language plugins from executing?

I believe the issue stems from the fact that I am scanning .groovy files with my language plugin. I would like to be able to do this without triggering the Groovy sensor from the Groovy plugin.

Here is the relevant part of the sonar-runner output (the lines beginning with ** are what I want to stop):

```
09:35:07.647 INFO  - -------------  Scan Generic Plugin Test
09:35:07.650 INFO  - Load module settings
09:35:07.909 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Sonar Way,language=gnrc]
09:35:07.922 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
09:35:07.922 INFO  -   **/package-info.java
09:35:07.962 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
09:35:07.986 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2014-08-14)
09:35:07.996 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-07-15, analysis of 2014-08-13 09:38:32.24)
09:35:08.014 INFO  - Compare to previous version
09:35:08.213 INFO  - Base dir: /workspace
09:35:08.213 INFO  - Working dir: /workspace/.sonar
09:35:08.213 INFO  - Source dirs: /workspace
09:35:08.213 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
09:35:11.986 INFO  - Sensor Generic Source Importer...
09:35:15.361 INFO  - Sensor Generic Source Importer done: 3375 ms
09:35:15.361 INFO  - Sensor GenericSensor...
09:35:16.007 INFO  - Sensor GenericSensor done: 646 ms
**09:35:16.007 INFO  - Sensor GroovySensor...
**09:35:23.745 INFO  - GMetrics completed: 4033ms
**09:35:24.528 INFO  - Sensor GroovySensor done: 8521 ms
**09:35:24.528 INFO  - Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor...
**09:35:24.529 INFO  - No Cobertura report provided (see 'sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath' property)
**09:35:24.529 INFO  - Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor done: 1 ms
...
...
```

Here is my sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.example.test:generictest
sonar.projectName=Generic Plugin Test
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectDescription=
sonar.language=gnrc
sonar.sources=.
sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue with a Java project where the JavaScript sensor was being executed. I resolved the issue with the following Sonar properties

```
sonar.language=java
sonar.exclusions=*.js
```

I don't think the above is the absolute correct way to achieve what you want but I couldn't find any properties to disable a sensor so I went with the above.